# java socket tips regarding storing the socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have create  one chat application in java. Front end I made as Eclipse RCP. Earlier I created one view
and there it shows how many users are logged. Now I created another view which is anther plugin project
and I want to do differnt activities in that view. So is that okay if I created one session concept in my
chat application where key will be username and value will be the socket.  Is this a good approch?
Because I want to get the socket object inside the newly created object. I dont want to create the new socket object.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an alternative? If you need the socket in two views, then you will have to keep them in a central place and you will need to give them a key that you can pass around to the views. So the approach sounds reasonable to me.

But maybe it would be better to wrap the sockets in a helper class that implements methods that your views need. This way, you can keep all the common code in a single place.

What is more important: If you ever need to change the chat protocol, you can now do it in your helper class and the views don't have to change.

To do that, turn your manager into an OSGi service and let Eclipse inject it into your views. See [Build lightweight OSGi applications with Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-osgi/index.html)

Comment: I kept in a central place. I used one communication manager which is client side used to communicate with server. So now in the view also I should create the communication manager in order to communicate with the server. So it creates different socket object which I dont want. That is the  problem. In future if I want to make another view, again these problem will happen. How to make this as central place and assure only one socket for one client?

Comment: Move the view's communication manager into a new plug-in so that both views can use them.

Comment: But in both views, it will be created more than two time for one client right? That is the problem. I planned to use, when the user logged in, I get one socket object and store into one hash map against the key as as the logged in user name and value will be  socket. So when ever I want that particular socket object I will get from the map. Is that ok?

Comment: Turn it into a service. See this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-osgi/index.html

Comment: This information is good. Thanks. But without through OSGI, Cant we do it?Thats what I was looking for. Becuase I may change my front end to some other technology. Still  I should be able to use.

Comment: Looking up a service is just a few lines of code. They are easy to replace if OSGi isn't around.